# Definitive books/resources on web application scalability?

Tags: web-applications, scalability

What are the best, up-to-date, resources on web application scalability?

Any resource will do, books recommendations are preferred.

Alternative question - if you needed to recommend one book which covers web scalability, which would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly different answer than you may be looking for, but check out some of the [slideshows on it](http://www.slideshare.net/group/webapps-scalability/slideshows) at SlideShare. Also, look for blogs of developers at semi-large to large companies.  I've read quite a few interesting articles that talk about scalability issues.

I also recommend checking out [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/).

Comment: high scalability is a no-brainer :) Slides are usually hard to understand out of context, but I will take a look. Thanks.